# space between consecutive references in text

Tags: spacing, biblatex

Based on code from biblatex-apa, I have created a `\fullcitebib` command to enter complete references in the text. I can use multiple commands of this type to create lists of complete references without having to follow the ordering of citations in the document. This leads to a lot of white space between references, presumably because it is processing the references as items in separate lists. Is it possible to avoid having this space between consecutive `\fullcitebib` commands?

**EDIT:** Ah, I can avoid the vertical space issue with a different definition of `\fullcitebib` which doesn't use list items, which gets closer to what I want.  There is still the problem that the references are indented (which I don't want) as well as having hanging indentation (which I do want). Any suggestions as to how to get the references against the left margin, without a manual `\noindent`? Sample code and output below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
            style=authoryear,%
            ]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@book{tras1996,
    Address = {London},
    Author = {R. L. Trask},
    Publisher = {Routledge},
    Title = {A dictionary of phonetics and phonology},
    Year = {1996}}
@book{crys2010,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Author = {David Crystal},
    Edition = {3},
    Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    Title = {The {C}ambridge Encyclopaedia of Language},
    Year = {2010}}
@book{matt2005,
    Address = {Oxford},
    Author = {Matthews, P.H.},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Title = {The Concise {O}xford Dictionary of Linguistics},
    Year = {2005}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib} 

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcitebib}
  {}
  {\hangindent=3em\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry\par}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}
   }

\begin{document}

\fullcitebib{tras1996}\fullcitebib{crys2010}\fullcitebib{matt2005}

The references above should have a hanging indent, as they do now, but be against
the left margin, like the references list below.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind to mark in the image, which lines should be intended?

Comment: code and image modified

Comment: Would `{\hskip-\parindent\hangindent=\parindent\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry\par}` do the job?

Comment: The purpose of this command "I can use multiple commands of this type to create lists of complete references without having to follow the ordering of citations in the document." sounds a bit odd. What exactly do you use the command for? You can sort bibliographies and citations independently. I don't think it is a good idea to use `\fullcitebib` to get the entire bibliography with a different sorting.

Comment: I don't want to use `\fullcitebib` for an entire bibliography.  I want to use it to include a small number of full references within a document (within a handout for a class, for example).

Comment: @samcarter that seems to work -- thanks!

Comment: @GarethWalker But now that I understand the use case, I think there are better ways, see the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To answer your problem**

To insert a small subset of references, you can simply use `refsection` and get a good formatting without any hacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@book{tras1996,
Address = {London},
Author = {R. L. Trask},
Publisher = {Routledge},
    Title = {A dictionary of phonetics and phonology},
Year = {1996}}
    @book{crys2010,
    Address = {Cambridge},
    Author = {David Crystal},
Edition = {3},
Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
Title = {The {C}ambridge Encyclopaedia of Language},
Year = {2010}}
@book{matt2005,
Address = {Oxford},
Author = {Matthews, P.H.},
Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
Title = {The Concise {O}xford Dictionary of Linguistics},
Year = {2005}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib.bib} 

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
        \newrefcontext[sorting=none]
    \nocite{tras1996,crys2010}
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{refsection}


\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]
\nocite{tras1996,crys2010,matt2005}
The references above should have a hanging indent, as they do now, but be against
the left margin, like the references list below.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

**To answer your question:**

The first line of your custom reference gets indented, as it is the first line of a paragraph. This can be reverted by a liitle hack: `\hskip-\parindent`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
style=authoryear,%
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@book{tras1996,
Address = {London},
Author = {R. L. Trask},
Publisher = {Routledge},
Title = {A dictionary of phonetics and phonology},
Year = {1996}}
@book{crys2010,
Address = {Cambridge},
Author = {David Crystal},
Edition = {3},
Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
Title = {The {C}ambridge Encyclopaedia of Language},
Year = {2010}}
@book{matt2005,
Address = {Oxford},
Author = {Matthews, P.H.},
Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
Title = {The Concise {O}xford Dictionary of Linguistics},
Year = {2005}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib.bib} 

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcitebib}
{}
{\hskip-\parindent\hangindent=\parindent\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry\par}
{}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}
}

\begin{document}

\fullcitebib{tras1996}\fullcitebib{crys2010}\fullcitebib{matt2005}

The references above should have a hanging indent, as they do now, but be against
the left margin, like the references list below.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for both parts.  I can see that the refsection method is probably best. Is it possible to have a refsection where the entries are unsorted, where other citations are sorted with `sortcites=true` and `sorting=ynt` in the preamble? It seems I can change the sorting in the refsection with e.g.  `\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt]` in the refsection, but what if I want them unsorted?

Comment: @GarethWalker Can you have a look at my edited code?

Comment: great - that seems to work perfectly. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should have stuck with the original definition based on `biblatex-apa`.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcitebib}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}%
   \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
     \finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
   \list{}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
   \item}
  {\usedriver
     {}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry}
  {\item}
  {\endlist
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Instead of

```
\fullcitebib{tras1996}\fullcitebib{crys2010}\fullcitebib{matt2005}
```

which starts a new list for every entry (as you rightly noted), you should have used

```
\fullcitebib{tras1996,crys2010,matt2005}
```

where all three entries are in the same list

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,%
            style=authoryear,%
            ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcitebib}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}%
   \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
     \finalandcomma\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
   \list{}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
   \item}
  {\usedriver
     {}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry}
  {\item}
  {\endlist
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

\fullcitebib{sigfridsson}\fullcitebib{worman}\fullcitebib{cicero}

\fullcitebib{sigfridsson,worman,cicero}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: As far as I can tell with this approach a`\fullcitebib` command containing multiple citations will order them in the same way as other kinds of citations in the document. Sometimes (but not always) I want them in a different order (e.g. instead of chronologically, in alphabetical order, order of importance, or whatever).

Comment: @GarethWalker That is only if you have the `sortcites` option enabled. As I said in my comment above, if you want to have the whole block of references again there are other and better ways to get a different sorting. (samcarter's answer shows some.)